# FN keys not working on laptop

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, fn-key

On a Toshiba Satellite L305-S5955, functions keys <kbd>F8</kbd> through <kbd>F12</kbd> are not working.

Originally this laptop had Vista and I installed Windows 8. Can somebody tell me what I need to do to have the keys work again?

Comment: What did those keys do earlier? Most likely you had some Toshiba software installed that mapped those keys to certain functions/programs. If that's the case you need to install that software or look for alternatives.

Comment: if that's the case. what is the software should be installed?

Comment: You'll have to check Toshiba's driver/software page for your laptop model.

Comment: You can give your F8-F12 a try with external keyboard attached. This can give you a clue about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to install the Toshiba Value Added Package as it'll install the functionality to enable the keys and other functions.

Source: [https://support.toshiba.com/support/viewContentDetail?contentId=3368363#TOSHIBA Value Added Package](https://support.toshiba.com/support/viewContentDetail?contentId=3368363#TOSHIBA%20Value%20Added%20Package)